# Manually Implementing string.IndexOf

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I need to implement string.IndexOf functionality without using any c# string search related built in methods.

Could you suggest a simple algorithm for this. Search does not involve really large strings. you can assume the maximum lenghth of the string to be search as 1000 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this sounds like homework, I'll provide guidance instead of a solution.  There is a great overview of string search algorithms on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Try implementing the Naïve string search as a good introduction to the subject.

> The simplest and least efficient way to see where one string occurs
>   inside another is to check each place it could be, one by one, to see
>   if it's there. So first we see if there's a copy of the needle in the
>   first character of the haystack; if not, we look to see if there's a
>   copy of the needle starting at the second character of the haystack;
>   if not, we look starting at the third character, and so forth. In the
>   normal case, we only have to look at one or two characters for each
>   wrong position to see that it is a wrong position, so in the average
>   case, this takes O(n + m) steps, where n is the length of the haystack
>   and m is the length of the needle; but in the worst case, searching
>   for a string like "aaaab" in a string like "aaaaaaaaab", it takes
>   O(nm) steps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the implementations in other languages. E.g. Java?

The source code for these is widely available, learning from experts is always a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Another good piece of guidance is to think about "Can I avoid some amount of searches?" For instance, if your search string is `aaaa` and the searched string is `aaabaaaabaaa` and you start at position [0] do you still have to search at position [1]?

Also, which is the best character in the search string to begin matching against? If your search string is `abcd` and your searched string is `aababceabcd` does that suggest some aspects of how your matching loop might be structured?